# Apply bootstrap 4 classes to several td in a table

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

Is there any way or workaround to apply several twitter bootstrap 4.5 classes to several `td` tags without repeat them or using jquery? I just want avoid the lot of data written in the html protocol.

For e.g., having 500 rows with the following classes (there are more, is just an e.g.)

```
   <td class="align-middle text-center bg-dark text-light">
```

Any kind of write something like

```
   <td class="my-collection-of-bs-classes">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple with sass just use [`@extend`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend)

```
.my-collection-of-bs-classes {
  @extend .align-middle;
  @extend .text-center;
  @extend .bg-dark;
  @extend .text-light;
}
```